# Get exact number in inches with LeftIndent using VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, indentation

I'm trying to get a `0.3"` value for the indentation before text of bullets using VBA in PowerPoint.

I'm using `.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 22` in my macro, but this creates a `0.31"` indentation value.

`21.4` gets me a `0.29"` indentation and `21.5` a `0.31"` - I can't figure out how to get `0.30"` - any idea?

I have the same issue to get a `0.45"` indentation value (I am using `33` as value but this create a `0.46"` indentation)

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: How about using 21.45?

Comment: Indents, like most values in PPT, are measured in points, 72 points to the inch.  Have you tried .3 * 72 or 21.6 points?  And if you're looking at the distance from the left edge of the shape holding the text to the left edge of the text, are you taking into account the textbox's left margin?

Comment: 21.45, 21.6 and 0.3*72 get me 0.31'' and not 0.30'' unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

Use the conversion function Application.InchesToPoints

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that Application.InchesToPoints doesn't exist in PowerPoint : https://bettersolutions.com/vba/numbers/measurements-inches-points.htm

Comment: In PowerPoint am inch is  72 point (source Google) 22/72=.3055